# How to iterate through a JSON array and display specific information based on an API response value in React?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I'm building a ReactJS web application, I have a JSON array:

```
[{
  "2149166938": {
    "name": "Classical-42",
    "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/e6885dab15cafeaf0dbf80f1ff9b5eb8.jpg"
  },
  "2149166939": {
    "name": "Countess SA/2",
    "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/de8906743db9fce201b33802c8498943.jpg"
  },
  "2154059444": {
    "name": "The Long Goodbye",
    "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/fe07633a2ee87f0c00d5b0c0f3838a7d.jpg"
  }
}]
```

When I make a call to an API I am returned a value of lets say `2154059444` which is the same value as the last object in my JSON file.

How would I iterate through the JSON file to find the object which has a value of `2154059444` and then access and render it's child values like name or icon?

Comment: Your array seems to be malformed, there is a curly brace unneeded at the beginning or you missed a curly brace at the end

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini so there is! Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple. JSON is equivalent to Javascript object. So you can do something like `result[0]["2154059444"]`. You might want to use `JSON.parse` for converting the JSON string to Javascript object.

Comment: be careful with your data types. `"2154059444" is not equal to 2154059444`

Comment: Thanks this sorted it for me!

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this. Your array is not proper please edit.
Create filtered data :

//here  i am addding single dummy point you can make your function
l

```
et filteredData = [].concat(data.map(test => {
        if(Object.keys(test)[0]==="2154059444"){
          return test["2154059444"]
        }
      })).filter(Boolean)
```

and simply render it app like this .

```
{ filteredData.map(test => <div>{test.name}</div>)}
```

Here is live [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fc825a)